# Upload same documents to Dropbox .NET SDK

Tags: c#, dropbox

I have a web API function that successfully upload files to Dropbox (using their new .NET SDK) and then gets shared links to the uploaded files (each document a time).

```
private async Task<string> Upload(DropboxClient dbx, string localPath, string remotePath)
    {
        const int ChunkSize = 4096 * 1024;
        using (var fileStream = File.Open(localPath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            if (fileStream.Length <= ChunkSize)
            {
                WriteMode mode = new WriteMode();

                FileMetadata fileMetadata = await dbx.Files.UploadAsync(remotePath, body: fileStream, mode: mode.AsAdd, autorename: true);
                //set the expiry date
                var settings = new SharedLinkSettings(expires: DateTime.Today.AddDays(7));

                SharedLinkMetadata sharedLinkMetadata = await dbx.Sharing.CreateSharedLinkWithSettingsAsync(fileMetadata.PathLower, settings);
                return sharedLinkMetadata.Url;
            }
            else
            {
                await this.ChunkUpload(dbx, remotePath, fileStream, ChunkSize);
            }
            return "error";
        }
    }
```

That usually works fine but when I upload the exact same document (name and content) twice, nothing happens and I do need to have both files stored in my Dropbox account.

It can be as much same documents as needed (not only two), my best scenario would be to have the second document (and third etc..) automatically renamed and uploaded to Dropbox.

Any idea on how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I post the answer, maybe it will help someone.. I spent long time till I figure it out.

This is the code that checks if a file already exists in Dropbox.

If the file exists it checks if a link was shared for this file and based on the result it generates/retrieves a/the shared link.

```
private async Task<string> Upload(DropboxClient dbx, string localPath, string remotePath)
    {
        const int ChunkSize = 4096 * 1024;
        using (var fileStream = File.Open(localPath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            if (fileStream.Length <= ChunkSize)
            {
                WriteMode mode = new WriteMode();
                FileMetadata fileMetadata = await dbx.Files.UploadAsync(remotePath, body: fileStream, mode: mode.AsAdd, autorename: true);
                //set the expiry date
                var existingDoc = await dbx.Files.GetMetadataAsync(remotePath);
                if (existingDoc.IsFile)
                {
                    var sharedLink = await dbx.Sharing.ListSharedLinksAsync(remotePath);
                    var settings = new ListSharedLinksArg(remotePath);
                    ListSharedLinksResult listSharedLinksResult = await dbx.Sharing.ListSharedLinksAsync(remotePath);
                    if (listSharedLinksResult.Links.Count > 0)
                    {
                        return listSharedLinksResult.Links[0].Url;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var sharedLinkSettings = new SharedLinkSettings(expires: DateTime.Today.AddDays(7));
                        SharedLinkMetadata sharedLinkMetadata = await dbx.Sharing.CreateSharedLinkWithSettingsAsync(remotePath, sharedLinkSettings);
                        return sharedLinkMetadata.Url;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    var settings = new SharedLinkSettings(expires: DateTime.Today.AddDays(7));
                    SharedLinkMetadata sharedLinkMetadata = await dbx.Sharing.CreateSharedLinkWithSettingsAsync(fileMetadata.PathLower, settings);
                    return sharedLinkMetadata.Url;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var sharedLink = await this.ChunkUpload(dbx, remotePath, fileStream, ChunkSize);
                return sharedLink;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you upload the same exact content to the same path again, the Dropbox API won't produce a conflict or another copy of the file, as nothing changed. (Edit: you can force a conflict even for identical contents by using `strictConflict=true`, e.g., on [`UploadAsync`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesUserRoutes_UploadAsync_1.htm)).

If you want another copy of the same data in your account, you can specify the different desired path when calling [`UploadAsync`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesUserRoutes_UploadAsync_1.htm) the second time.

Or, more efficiently, you can use [`CopyAsync`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesUserRoutes_CopyAsync_1.htm) to make a copy of the file already on Dropbox.

Comment: Thank you, the problem is that I don't know in advance if the document already exist or not, so how can the `copyAsync` method help? And if let's say I do keep the same code, when I try to get a shared link, I'm getting a `shared link already exist error`?

Comment: You can use [`getMetadataAsync`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesUserRoutes_GetMetadataAsync_1.htm) to check if a file already exists. If a link already exists for a file, you can retrieve it using [`ListSharedLinksAsync`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Sharing_Routes_SharingUserRoutes_ListSharedLinksAsync_1.htm).

Comment: Would you be able to give an example?

Comment: I don't have a sample for these available. Please give it a try and open a new question if you run in to any issues.

Comment: Just one more question, if the shared link already exist, what about the expiry? How can I set up even the existing links to expire in 7 days?

Comment: You can check the [`Expires`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/P_Dropbox_Api_Sharing_SharedLinkMetadata_Expires.htm) property on any returned [`SharedLinkMetadata`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/T_Dropbox_Api_Sharing_SharedLinkMetadata.htm) to see the expiration information. You can modify the expiration on any existing link using [`ModifySharedLinkSettingsAsync`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Sharing_Routes_SharingUserRoutes_ModifySharedLinkSettingsAsync_1.htm).